# How to obtain a List of Active Service Entry Points?

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle

When debuging a Batch one has to STRDBG and set a "SBREAK", at times my fellow Developers are debuging RPGLE service programs exposed as a webservice. At times this causes the website to "Hang" until the breakpoint is released.

Is there an IBMi API to retrieve a list of current service entry points (SBREAKs)?

**Related Resources:**

- [IBMi Listing of APIs](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_72/apifinder/apifinder40.htm)
- [IBMi Debugging APIs](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_72/apis/debug1.htm)
- [Service-Entry-Points-Help-Simplify-CGI-Debugging](http://www.ibmsystemsmag.com/ibmi/developer/general/Service-Entry-Points-Help-Simplify-CGI-Debugging)

**Proposed Listing should contain:**

1. **Registered Service Entry Points**

   - Job Detail: JobNumber/UserName/JobName
   - Program Detail: Library/Program/Module
   - BreakPoint Detail: Statement Number / Break Condition
2. **For Active Break Points**

   - Job Detail: JobNumber/UserName/JobName
   - Program Detail: Library/Program/Module
   - BreakPoint Detail: Statement Number

Comment: No answer yet, so SAD.

Comment: No direct answer, but what would you do if you had such a list?

Comment: @user2338816, Initially, I would use the list to know whom set the break point. Thus I would no longer have to shout across the office. WHO HAS A BREAK POINT ON PROGRAM XXXXX!!!

Comment: So not merely a list, but including details of the jobs that set them. Are there that many debug sessions _against production programs_ going on at once? (Are there that many developers with *SERVICE authority on a production system? IMO, should be **very** limited, one or two.)

Comment: @user2338816 Never said Production Environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Service jobs being debugged normally have the EVTW status. You can then look into this job's joblog and you may see messages that says this job is held/released by XXXXXXX user.

I would approach this problem using the `QUSLJOB` to get a list of jobs with the EVTW status in the sub system you want to target and from there you could get to the job log and call stack entries to try and pro-grammatically determine who is debugging which programs.

You could also wrap the strdbg, enddbg, strsrvjob and endsrvjob commands in your own commands and record in a table who is actively debugging at the time.

Hope this gets you closer to a solution.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.